# Schengen visa Multi-entry Question 25, 29 and 30?

Tags: visas, schengen

I'm applying for Schengen visa multi-entry but I don't know how to answer to Q 25, 29 and 30.

How do I fill in the dates? I only know about my first trip as I have booked it already but I'll be flying in/out of Schengen zone multi times over the next 12 months but the time/dates of my other trips are not known yet.

Here's the link to the form:

https://www.government.nl/binaries/government/documents/forms/2013/02/22/schengen-visa-application-form/Schengen+visa+application+january2017.pdf

Any hints and help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (but not 100%) that those fields apply to the first trip only.

Comment: But if I only add the dates for first trip they may issue a short term 90 days visa.

Comment: If they issue a short term visa you can apply for a second after your initial trip. Your subsequent applications will be made stronger for having followed the terms of the first visa they grant you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Schengen visa form, **you only enter the dates for the first trip that you will make into the Schengen Zone**. Information about subsequent trips can be included in the itinerary that you also have to submit as a part of your application. You may also include a letter explaining why you wish to enter the Schengen Zone multiple times.

However, keep in mind that despite all this, you may only receive a single entry visa. At the same time, many consulates may also issue a multiple entry visa even when you only indicate that you are planning to visit once.

Source: personal experience with applying for Schengen visas multiple times.

Comment: +1 to add that if this is your first time applying, you are more likely to receive a restricted visa.